# Snort - PCRE giving false postives

Tags: regex, pcre, snort

How to match a stream of hex characters say - |57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 20 37 20 48 6f 6d 65 20 50| using "pcre" option in Snort ? I want to match all values from 57 to 50 in the given stream. PCRE is only matching the first character i.e. 57 and giving false positives.

Comment: show us what has been tried so far..

Comment: pcre: "/|57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 20 37 20 48 6f 6d 65 20 50|/"

Comment: pcre: "/|57| && |69| && |6e| && |64| && |6f| && |77| && |73| && |20| && |37| && |20| && |48| && |6f| && |6d| && |65| && |20| && |50|/"

Comment: pcre: "/57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 20 37 20 48 6f 6d 65 20 50/". This is not working. If I put put the piped characters, it is working but there are too many false positives. It is not matching the entire thing. Not sure why.

Comment: what do you mean with a false positive here? also, are you trying to match each hex pair individually or the entire thing between the pipes?

Comment: Try `\|(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}\s*)+\|`

Comment: ArSEN, I am trying to configure rules to detect exploits and vulnerabilities using an intrusion detection system named Snort. However, to be sure that the exploit is detected, the entire thing between piped characters should be matched. However, that is not happening. It is matching only the first character that is 57 though the entire thing should be matched.

Comment: sin, I will try that. Can you explain me how you got there ? I need to detect other such sequences as well. Thanks.

Comment: sin, I tried it and it works. But, again there are false positives. Can you come with an expression which differentiates between - |57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 20 37 20 48 6f 6d 65 20 50| and |57 69 6e 64 6f 77 73 20 37 20 50 72 6f 66 65 73| ? The expression you have given will detect both. I want to differentiate between them because they belong to different exploits. Can you come up with a brute force approach i.e. 2 expressions each of which will only detect one sequence above and reject the other.

Comment: @RaaghavMathur - 57 - 50 is simply this `\|57\s*(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}\s*)*50\|`

Comment: If it works for you I'll post a formal answer and explanation.

Comment: @sln Hey, both the expressions given by you - \|(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}\s*)+\| and \|57\s*(?:[a-fA-F0-9]{2}\s*)*50\| work when tested on regex101.com. However, when tested with the rule, they do not work. I found something - /^[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{1000,}/R This works and detects the exploits. Can you please explain what this expression means ?

Comment: If you can explain what /^[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{1000,}/R means I think i will use this. I think PCRE for Snort works slightly differently. Thanks for all the help.

Comment: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9+/]{1000,}/R` is not a regex that will _**ever**_ match anything. Maybe in your interdimensional universe.

Comment: I think it has something to do with Snort intrusion detection system. Thanks for all the help. 